What is this bracket on the side of my shower called? I believe it may have held a soap dish

Looking to add something here so its not just raw metal.

I would say it's a soap dish bracket. Here's one from Zoro that would probably utilize the same hole. Don't use the old bracket because rust will probably run down the wall. You can always just remove the bracket and fill in the hole with matching grout or caulk if you don't want a soap dish.


I’d definitely remove the old one either way. It looks like you could cut yourself pretty badly on it if you lost your balance the wrong way.

If it's installed with a toggle bolt, you might lose it in the wall when you take out the screw.

@JimmyJames   I would guess that there are more toggle bolts lost in walls than are actually holding up something.. : -)
